# How to stub AJAX function using jasmine Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jasmine

Here is my code:

```
function sendRequestData(url, urlParameters) {
if (url != null && urlParameters != null) {
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Accept' : 'application/json'
        },
        contentType : 'application/json',
        data : JSON.stringify(urlParameters),
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data) {
            successCallBack(data)
        },
        error : function(data, status, errorThrown) {
            failCallBack(data, status, errorThrown)
        }
    });
```

I want to stub the function and check the response. Is there anyway I can do that using jasmine-ajax plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
it("should receive a successful response", function() {
  spyOn($, "ajax").andCallFake(function(e) {
    e.success({});
  });
  spyOn(window, "successCallBack");
  spyOn(window, "failCallBack");

  sendRequestData('dummyURL', ['dummyParam1', 'dummyParam2']);
  expect(window.successCallBack).toHaveBeenCalled();  //Verifies this was called
  expect(window.failCallBack).not.toHaveBeenCalled();  //Verifies this was NOT called
});
```

For failure, you replace callFake with `e.error()` and reverse your asserts for `successCallBack` and `failCallBack`

Can refer to the link below for further information
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/testing-ajax-event-handlers-using-jasmine-spies.html

Comment: Modified the answer.  Thanks @Reti43 for guidance. I am fairly new here